# How to Mock Actions (negative and positive tests) to throw an error on api call in Unit Tests of Pinia stores with vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, pinia, vitest

I am new to Vitest and also Pinia, used with with VUE3 (options api), I am trying to test an action in pinia eg:-

```
loadSettings(){
 return return new Promise((resolve) => {
          getSettings()
         .then((response)=>{
            this.settings=response.data;
             resolve(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
              appStore.showError({
                response: error,
                customErrorMessage: "Error!",
              });
            reject(error);
            });
}
```

which calls an open-api function (axios call) as follows :

```
let myStore = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
    // create an instance of the data store
    myStore = useMyStore();
    appStore= useAppStore();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    vi.restoreAllMocks();
  });

test("load settings", async () => {
    const loadSettingsSpy = vi.spyOn(myStore, "loadSettings");

    loadSettingsSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => settings);

    await myStore.loadSettings();
    expect(loadSettingsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

this test seems to work.

I am trying to mock the error for the same action which goes to the catch block.

For that I tried :

```
test("load settings- error on loading", async () => {
     const loadSettingsSpy = vi.spyOn(myStore, "loadSettings");
     const errorSpy=vi.spyOn(appStore, "showError");

    loadSettingsSpy.mockImplementation(() => new Error("Error"));

    await myStore.loadSettings();
    expect(loadSettingsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}
```

It fails, is there any way i can mock an error from the api call ?

TIA